# how can define shortcuts to specific actions in the app?

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, android-shortcut

If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, how can define shortcuts to specific actions in the app. Shortcuts let users quickly start common or recommended tasks within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this Android documentation for shortcuts to specific actions

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Comment: Such answers must be posted as comments rather than an individual answer